# For loop which equates function to a variable

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a function

```py
def totally(x,name):
   return x+1+str(name)
```

and list

`alpha = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`
`beta = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']`

How do i assign variables with the output of the for-loop.

example

```py
for a,b in zip(alpha,beta):
   var[i]=totally(a,b)
```

to get 6 variables var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6

Comment: What does totally do, does it even run?

Comment: No, it doesn't run. `x` is an `int` and the function has an undefined return type

Comment: What is the *real* problem you need to solve? Why do you want to create six different variables dynamically? Why can't you simply use a list with six elements and use standard list indexing?

Answer (score 0):

[List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)!

```py
var = [totally(a, b) for a, b in zip(alpha, beta)]
```